# Why are lvalues converted to values in certain places and not others?

Tags: c, operators

Consider this code:

```
int x = 99;
int * p = &x;
*p = *p + 1;
```

Why do the `*p` on the left side and right side of the `=` operator differ?

How does the compiler know to use the left `*p` to be the object `x` and the right `*p` to be the value of `x`?

Specifically, if the compiler evaluates `*p` to be the value of `x`, why does the `*p` on the left side not evaluate to 99, creating an erroneous assignment to a literal: `99 = 99 + 1;`?
Similarly, if the compiler evalues `*p` to be the object `x` (assuming that that is what the left operand of the `=` operator expects), why does not the `*p` on the right hand side also evaluate to the object `x`?

Comment: C or C++? Choose one, they're different languages. Moreover, in `*p` you're dereferencing `p`. This is the very basic of C++, refer to a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: `*p` is not the address of `x`.

Comment: You're assuming that "value" and "type" are the only properties of an expression, but they are not. There are also "value category" (`*p` is lvalue so it's allowed here, `99` is prvalue and it's not), and "address".

Comment: This is no different from `x = x + 1`

Comment: There is no "literal" in your code, other than the `99` that is used to initialize the `x` **variable**.

Comment: ... if you're teaching C or C++ and don't understand what's happening in this code, then I don't think there's much than anyone on S.O. can do (politely) to help you.

Comment: @Barmar I'll try again with `x=x+1` how does the compiler knows to give 99 AND 1 as arguments for the + operator. But to give the address of x as the first argument to the = operator?

Comment: `*p` is an [_lvalue expression_](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category). It is being used on both sides of an assignment operator. On the left it's being written, and on the right it's being read.

Comment: @AdrianMole Of course i understand what happens in this code.. read my question again. I am trying to explain to a student how the compiler knows to evaluate differently the same expression. what is the set of rules that defines when an expression is evaluated to an integer, and when it is evaluated to the be the address of the variable  (to be written to)

Comment: No offence, but if you can't clearly explain something to someone, then you don't understand it. Even in this very comment, you're saying that there's some difference between the two `*p`, but there's none.

Comment: I think it's fair to expect a teacher to have a deeper understanding of the language than what is being demonstrated here. That said, your student asked a good question that was beyond you, and this is a learning experience for _you_.

Comment: Answer to Q1: they don't differ. Q2: the question is based on a false premise.  Q3. the question is also based on a false premise. Q4. the question is based on a false premise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The result of the dereference operator `*` is an **lvalue**.  It references an object (not just a value) that can be assigned to.

This means that `*p` is an lvalue denoting the object that `p` points to, specifically `x`.

When an lvalue is used in an expression such as `*p + 1` or `x + 1`, the lvalue is converted to a value and is no longer an lvalue.  This conversion does *not* happen when the lvalue is the left operand of the assignment operator.

This conversion is detailed in section 6.3.2.1p2 of the [C standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof`
> operator, the unary `&` operator, the `++` operator, the `--`
> operator, or the left operand of the `.` operator or an assignment
> operator, an lvalue that does not have array type is converted to the
> value stored in the designated object (and is no longer an lvalue);
> this is called *lvalue conversion*

So the expression `*p = *p + 1` is effectively the same as `*p = 99 + 1`.  The same goes for `x = x + 1`.

Comment: This quote is pure gold

Comment: I've closed this question as a duplicate (because I think it is); however, your answer here would be very valuable (IMHO) as an answer to the linked dupe.

Comment: @AdrianMole Isn't it better to use the question with better answers as the duplicate target?

Comment: @Unmitigated Possibly. Or maybe a merge would be in order? I've just asked about that in the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/54961642#54961642) chat-room.

Comment: @Unmitigated The 'original' is not a *bad* question and it also has some decent answers. I wouldn't want any/either to be 'lost' to the wider community.

Answer (score 2):

C and C++, like many languages, distinguish between L-values and R-values. These terms refer to the way an expression is treated when it's on the left or right side of an assignment.

There are a number of intricacies, but for the purpose of answering your question simply, an L-value refers to a location, while an R-value is any general value (like the amount in a numeric type, or all the contents of a structure).

So when you write:

```
L-value = R-value
```

it means to copy the R-value into the location described by the L-value.

The simplest case is an ordinary variable assignment:

```
x = x + 1;
```

On the right side, `x` is an R-value; we get the number 99 from it, add 1 to that, producing the value `100`. On the left side, `x` is an L-value that refers to the memory address of the variable, and we store `100` in that location.

It's no different when you replace `x` with `*p`.